# Reference for the Landau-Lifshitz system

Tags: resource-recommendations, chaos-theory, complex-systems, non-linear-systems

I'm interested in understanding the dynamics of the [discrete Landau-Lifshitz system](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=discrete+Landau+Lifshitz+equations). It's solutions to equations like
$$\frac{\partial X_n}{\partial t} = X_n\times (X_{n-1}+X_{n+1})$$
where the $X_n$ are unit vectors in spheres that sit on a discrete lattice (parameterized by $n$, and possibly finite with boundary conditions or infinite). This system is Hamiltonian, but apparently it is also very chaotic/non-integrable.

I'm not interested in understanding the associated quantum or continuum system (although I'm aware they are related).

Does anyone know a good paper that discusses the dynamics of these classical systems? In particular, one that explains their non-integrability and chaotic behaviour?

I'm sorry if this question isn't appropriate here.

Comment: This is currently the reference I'm working with since it seems to be the most mathematical/recent/comprehensive, but it doesn't prove or explain any details. http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.1005v1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about mathematics, not physics.